# Type safety with different generic values in collection

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have an interface like this;

```
interface Validator<T>{
    void validate<T value>    
}
```

And these implementations ;

```
class StringValidator implements Validator<String>{
    void validate<String value>{}
}
class OrderValidator implements Validator<Order>{
    void validate<Order value>{}
}
```

In ValidatorRegisterer class I have a map;

```
class ValidationRegisterer{
    Map<String, Validator> validatorsForPath = new HashMap<String, Validator>();

    public Map<String, Validator> registerers(){
        return validatorsForPath;
    }

    public void register(String path, Validator validator){
        validatorsForPath.put(path, validator);
    }
}
```

What I want is to iterate over this map in ValidationManager class with type safety;

```
class ValidationManager<RootObject>{
    List<ValidationRegisterer> validationRegisterers;

    public ValidationManager(List<ValidationRegisterer> validationRegisterers){
        this.validationRegisterers = validationRegisterers;
    }

    public void validate(RootObject object){
        for(ValidationRegisterer validationRegisterer in validationRegisterers){

            for(String path : validationRegisterer.keySet()){

                Object value = object.getPath(path);
                Validator validator = validationRegisterer.get(path);
                validator.validate(value);
                //this line gets unchecked call to validate(T) warning and I want to get rid of it
                //the problem is validationRegisterers map can contain both StringValidator and OrderValidator, 
                //so the value can be a String or an Order
                //do I have to cast the value to the type of validator's T type?
            }
        }
    }

    Map<String, Validator> validatorsForPath = new HashMap<String, Validator>();
}
```

I tried to explain the situation in the last code sample comments.

Comment: What is `RootObject`? Can you show us the class?

Comment: Note that you are using the `Validator` raw type in `Map<String, Validator>`.  You should use `Map<String, Validator<?>` to have a map from `String` to any kind of `Validator`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare as follows to remove warnings :

```
Validator<Object> validator = validationRegisterer.get(path);
```

In this case you are declaring the validator reference that would work on Object type.
later you can typecast to Order or String after doing an instanceof test.

Comment: That won't work: the returned validator is not necessarily a `Validator<Object>` since Java generics are not covariant.

Comment: @herman : yes you are right. It would remove all the warnings but it isn't a solution. But then if the user is mixing both types then what is the use of generic here.There's no point in using generics here.What do u say?

Comment: 1. It will not remove warnings.  The OP uses a raw type `Validator` in `Map<String, Validator>`, which requires unchecked conversion to convert to `Validator<Object>`.  Fixing the map by making it `Map<String, Validator<?>`, which is what it's supposed to be, will make sure that assignment to `Validator<Object>` won't even compile, as the values in the map are necessarily all of type `Validator<Object>`.  That is because a `Validator<String>` is not a subtype of `Validator<Object>`.

Comment: (^^^ should be "NOT necessarily all of type `Validator<Object>`)

2. You are right that if the validators are not used in any other context, generics don't add much.  But at least there must be some code where the validators are instantiated, it could add type safety there.  Also, by using the type T in the `validate(T value)` method ensures that any casting must have occurred before calling the validate method, so that each validator implementation doesn't have to do it's own type checking.  My 2nd solution in my answer makes use of this by putting the type check in 1 place (`PathValidator`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make ValidationRegisterer class generic like this:

```
class ValidationRegisterer<T extends Validator> {
    Map<String, T> validatorsForPath = new HashMap<String, T>();

    public Map<String, T> registerers(){
        return validatorsForPath;
    }

    public void register(String path, T validator){
        validatorsForPath.put(path, validator);
    }
}
```

And then maintain separate lists for these two types of ValidationRegisterer

```
class ValidationManager {
    List<ValidationRegisterer<StringValidator>> strValidationRegisterers;
    List<ValidationRegisterer<OrderValidator>> ordValidationRegisterers;
    ....  
}
```

Comment: This assumes that he knows all the kinds of possible validators, and this class needs to be modified if a new kind of validator is created.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that with "type safety" you mean that you want to be certain that the object returned for a certain path is really of the type that the associated `Validator` accepts.

One problem is that the type parameter for the `Validator` is not available at compile time since, as you say yourself, any kind of `Validator` can be in the map.

Also, `object.getPath(path)` will always return an `Object` which will always need casting at runtime, so the fact that the `validate` method limits its argument to type `T` is of little use.

So the best you can do is make validation fail fast in case the object is not of the correct type.

A solution would be to
1. store the `Class` object for the `Validator`,
2. let `validate` accept an `Object` as parameter and dynamically cast the object to the validator type at the beginning of the validate method.  This can be done in an abstract base class.

Example:

```
interface Validator<T> {
    void validate(Object value);
    Class<T> getType();
}

abstract class BaseValidator<T> implements Validator<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    public BaseValidator(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public final void validate(Object o) {
       doValidate(type.cast(o)); // wrong type will fail fast here
    }

    public final Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }

    protected abstract void doValidate(T value);
}

class StringValidator extends BaseValidator<String> {
    public StringValidator() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    protected void doValidate(String value) {
        // do actual string validation here
    }
}
```

An alternative solution if you want to keep `Object` out of the `Validator` interface would be to let the path be resolved by a type parameterized object that has a reference the validator and performs the dynamic cast, and keep that in your registry map as value:

```
interface Validator<T> {
    void validate(final T value);
}

class PathValidator<T> {
    private final Class<T>     type;
    private final Validator<T> validator;

    public PathValidator(final Class<T> type, final Validator<T> validator) {
        this.type = type;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public void validate(final RootObject object, final String path) {
        T value = type.cast(object.getPath(path)); // throws ClassCastException here if not the correct type
        validator.validate(value);
    }
}
```

You would then have a `Map<String, PathValidator<?>` in your `ValidationRegisterer` class.

I'd personally prefer this alternative solution.

Comment: I request you to show the implementation of ValidationRegister and ValidationManager class too.

Comment: @nishu For the first solution, the implementations stay exactly the same.  For the alternative solution, the change for `ValidationRegisterer` is mentioned in the answer (keeping a `Map<String, PathValidator<?>>`, where obviously the `PathValidator` must have been instantiated like `new PathValidator(String.class, StringValidator)`.  In `ValidationManager` you just get a `PathValidator<?>` from the `ValidationRegisterer`, on which you call `validate(object, path)` and it will resolve the path, dynamically cast the value and call the actual validator if the cast succeeds.